# Clarification of on-topic status

Tags: support, flagging, on-topic

I don't want to pick on [Nestor here](https://superuser.com/questions/315602/how-can-calibre-get-the-newspapers-for-free), as I think his question is good, but I'm questioning whether it is on-topic.

Let me clarify that I'm not complaining about flag weight, I promise.  However, I flagged this as off-topic, partly because I thought the software was for an e-Reader (forgive my ignorance of this fact), but mainly because it deals with decisions/contracts that were, in all likelihood, made at the corporate level.  Someone *may* have been able to answer for the company, but again, the likelihood of lightning striking twice and this issue returning in another asker's Google search is very slim.

Again, I know there was some initial confusion, and someone probably came along and said "of course this is PC/MAC software, this flag is crap", but I think the other component of it was overlooked, and since my comment wasn't addressing the corporate end of it, it was passed over.  I am also trying to make sure I didn't miss a hidden reason why it should be on topic.

Comment: I don't know anyone that disagreed with your judgement, so why are you questioning it?  I voted to close it, definitely off topic.

Comment: Thank you.  Usually I'm the one telling people on Meta.SO not to worry about flagging stuff.  I'm not blaming anyone, but this one just didn't sit right with me.  I think this is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I read from your question you are basically complaining about an flag of yours deemed invalid. Is that correct?

---

For what its worth, I voted to close the question, because it is entirely based on business models, licensing agreements, and – last but not least – speculation.

Another reason is that there is no real problem to be solved.

Yes, there is software involved, but this does not necessarily make it a practical and constructive question. It might be interesting, yes, but it isn't a good fit for Super User.  There is no *technical* answer to this question, only a business answer.

Comment: Sounds like a complaint here too, since he jumped to "flag weight" in there.

Comment: I have to agree. His problem isn't a software or technical problem, but rather a business problem

Comment: The flag *weight* part doesn't bother me, I've had plenty of flags rejected, but in this case it seems so clear cut, so I'm wondering if I missed an edge case or something.

Comment: @jonsca Can't speak for a mod here so you don't have to accept the answer!

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I'm not expecting the mod to have to justify his/her ruling.  I understand that different factors affect these types of moderator decisions.  Like I had said to Breakthrough, I usually strongly encourage people to take flagging outcomes in stride, so I need to heed my own advice :)  I reacted to the question that was posted, and expected that others would have the same reaction (which you did).